# Is possible to send push notificaiton to android and ios on list item add event from SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, notifications

I am making one application in Android and ios. That use backend as SharePoint.

Now I have to implement push notification on list item add.

I don't know how to do this and if it is even possible. If yes, how?

Any help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Flow with a custom RESTful API implementation. That custom RESTful service you create will be called by Flow whenever item is added to SP list and uses your chosen notification system to deliver push notification to the device, e.g. [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)